# "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'" in max

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
M = input("")
M = M.split(" ")
X = input("")
X = X.split(" ")
sum1 = 0
K = int(M[1])
while(K!=0):
    L = max(X)
    sum1 = sum1+int(L)
    X[X.index(max(X))] = int(max(X)) - 1
    K = K-1
print(sum1)
```

When I tried to execute the code with the following input

```
3 4  
1 2 4
```

I got the error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fg.py", line 9, in <module>
    L = max(X)
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

I didn't understand why the error getting raised when I execute this from the file. I tried the same in the terminal line by line and it worked. Please help me with this

Comment: You are probably using Python 2 in the terminal. In Python 2 it was allowed to compare `int` to `str`. In Python 3 it is not allowed because the result of that comparison was completely arbitrary and almost never useful in any context (any string was always "greater" than any integer)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

The input values which you are accepting from user are in `string` format. You need to convert it into `int`.

Modify `M = M.split(" ")` and `X = X.split(" ")` as shown below:

```
M = input("")
M = [int(i) for i in M.split(" ")]
X = input("")
X = [int(i) for i in X.split(" ")]
sum1 = 0
K = int(M[1])
while(K!=0):
    L = max(X)
    sum1 = sum1+int(L)
    X[X.index(max(X))] = int(max(X)) - 1
    K = K-1
print(sum1)
```

Comment: I know this works sir. First, let me know why error getting raised while executing the file but not in the terminal and that too the purpose of int is fulfilled by using int(L)

Comment: It's a fix, but the problem starts from the second iteration. There is no problem in finding the "max" in a list of strings (in this case it will be lexicographical max), but in the second iteration `X` contains both strings and an integer, that is when `max` fails in OPs code

Comment: You are finding ```Max(X)``` which gives you the error. And ```int(L)``` is in next line

Answer (score 0):

Answer by [DeepSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453822/deepspace)

It's a fix, but the problem starts from the second iteration. There is no problem in finding the "max" in a list of strings (in this case it will be lexicographical max), but in the second iteration X contains both strings and an integer, that is when max fails in OPs code